# Moving worker children to the QThread -> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, signals-slots, qthread, qprocess, qobject

I have a `QProcess` handler class (`processHandler`) that is called inside my `GUI` class as follows:

```
this->thread = std::make_shared<QThread>();
this->proc   = std::make_shared<processHandler>();

this->proc->moveToThread(thread.get());

connect(this->thread.get(), SIGNAL(started()), this->proc.get(), SLOT(runProcess()));
```

The `runProcess` SLOT is defined as follows in the `processhandler.cpp`:

```
#include "processhandler.h"

processHandler::processHandler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->proc = std::make_shared<QProcess>();
    connect(this->proc.get(), SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(printError()));
    connect(this->proc.get(), SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(onProcessFinished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));
}

processHandler::~processHandler(){}

void processHandler::runProcess()
{
    this->proc->setWorkingDirectory("path/to/application/dir");
    this->proc->start("command");
}

void processHandler::printError()
{
    QFile file("sys.log");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QByteArray byteArray = this->proc->readAllStandardError();
        QStringList strLines = QString(byteArray).split("\n");
        QString now = QTime::currentTime().toString();
    stream << "\n" << "Error Occurerd [" + now + "]: ";
        foreach (QString line, strLines)
        {
            stream << line << endl;
        }
    }
    file.flush();
    file.close();
}

void processHandler::onProcessFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus status)
{
    QFile file("sys.log");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QString now = QTime::currentTime().toString();
        stream << "\n" << "Process Exit [" + now + "]: " << QString::number(exitCode) << " with status " <<  QString::number(status);
    }
    file.flush();
    file.close();

    emit processFinished();
}
```

Once my `thread` starts inside the `GUI` class (`this->thread->start();`), I recieve the following message:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QProcess(0x15c50cc), parent's thread is QThread(0x15526f0), current thread is QThread(0x15bb654)
```

I understand from the message, that the children of `processHandler` live in another (`main`?) thread. But I have not find any step-by-step explanation on stack overflow, how to creat those children before moving to the `thread`. All hints or links that I missed are really appreciated.

Comment: You don't show the code that is actually trying to create child `QObject`s for the `QProcess` but... there's at least one obvious problem: `this->proc` doesn't have the `processHandler` as its parent and so will *not* be moved to the new worker thread.  So, you're moving the `processHandler` to a new thread but not its associated `QProcess`.

Comment: Also note that using `shared_ptr` to manage a `QObject` that is part of a hierarchy is generally a very bad idea -- both the `shared_ptr` *and* the object's parent will assume ownership and you'll probably end up with double-free errors and/or heap corruption.

Comment: @G.M. I do not understand why `this->proc` parent is not `processHandler`, while `this->proc` is a memebr of the class.

Comment: The fact that `proc` is a member of `processHandler` doesn't mean it's a child (in the `Qt` sense) of `processHandler`.  You need to fix that up yourself, e.g.`proc = new QProcess(this)` or `proc->setParent(this)`.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you a lot! I've absolutly missed that point! Solved my problem.